# HTML5 geolocation to get address

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

Is it possible to use the HTML5 geolocation to get an address instead of coordinates? I'm currently trying to make an app where I'm trying to use this tool this way, but I can't make it work.

```
var myAddress = Østerågade 17,
  9000 Aalborg(example address)

if (navigator.geolocation ==
  myAddress) {
  document.getElementById('home').style.display = "block";
} else {
  document.getElementById('home').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Your variable myAdress is likely not well formatted. What type does it need to be? String? Please provide your errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking at [reverse geocoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding).

> Reverse geocoding is the process of back (reverse) coding of a point
>   location (latitude, longitude) to a readable address or place name.

Here are some [useful links](https://gisgeography.com/reverse-geocoding-services-addresses-free-paid/) that provide you with this service and the one below is using [OpenStreetMaps](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) api

```js
$.ajax({ 
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=' + 44.968046 + '&lon=' + -94.420307 + '&namedetails=1',
  success: (response) => {
    if (response.display_name) {
      console.log(response.display_name);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```